# Does the PayPal Mobile SDK for Android work on an Amazon Kindle Fire HD 6?

Tags: android, paypal, kindle-fire

I can see the PayPal Mobile SDK requirements say it needs Android 2.2 or later, https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#requirements. And the Kindle runs a customised version of Android 4. So it should work, but I haven't found any mention of this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile SDK should work on the Kindle.  If you have a Kindle device, you can test it for yourself.